Getting latitude and longitude based on a location
I'm trying to get some latitudes and longitudes into my data based on locations which I do have and was wanted to know if there are any functions or packages that do this for my locations below? I have seen a package that looks potentially helpful called geocode but it requires an API code which I have no experience with at all.
locations = c('london','birmingham','madrid','paris','marseille')  


I think there are few APIs that do what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905216/16421247

Just a heads-up that geocoding at city level can vary a lot depending on the method you choose. For instance, comparing the results in the accepted answer (which uses OSM) and method = "arcgis", the coordinates vary by 2306.8173m,  719.1805m,  274.0518m, 3090.9632m, and  736.6551m. Not really an issue if it's just for display purposes, but needs to be considered if you're using the coordinates for analyses.

And don't be put off by needing an API key to use a service, think of it as just being a password. You need to sign up to the services that provide them, and sometimes supply credit card details as well (Google et al.) but they don't charge you for low-level use. Each geocoding package generally has easy to follow instructions regarding the use of API keys. Plus, plenty of related answers on SO.

Here is a solution using tidygeocoder package:
library(tidygeocoder)

locations = c('london','birmingham','madrid','paris','marseille')  

coordinates <- list()
for(i in locations){
  coordinates[[i]] <- geo(i)
}

print(coordinates)

$london
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  address   lat   long
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 london   51.5 -0.128

$birmingham
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  address      lat  long
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 birmingham  52.5 -1.90

$madrid
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  address   lat  long
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 madrid   40.4 -3.70

$paris
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  address   lat  long
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 paris    48.9  2.35

$marseille
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  address     lat  long
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 marseille  43.3  5.37

